# how to determine the users CKAccountStatus

Tags: ios, swift, accountmanager

Im trying to figure out how to determine the users iCloud status. I've read the developer reference outline and I still can't figure out how to determine this. Heres the code that I have extracted and tried to use in my app but it does not do anything as far as I can tell:

```
            enum CKAccountStatus : Int {
                case CouldNotDetermine
                case Available
                case Restricted
                case NoAccount
            }
```

I've been at this for awhile now and I know I'm missing something but I can't seem to figure out what it is! Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `CKContainer`'s `accountStatusWithCompletionHandler` which determines the status of the current user’s iCloud account asynchronously.

See the CloudKit Framework Reference for the `CKContainer` Class

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/CloudKit/Reference/CKContainer_class/index.html